# Django template tags {{for/empty}} for loop variable

Tags: javascript, python, django

To generate a set of Javascript variables with the relevant parameters from my Django application I have two nested for loops:

```
<script>
{% for model in models %} 
    {% for item in model.attribute|slice:":3" %}
        {% if forloop.first %} 
            var js_variable{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }} = [
        {% endif %}
            '{{ item.attribute }}' ,
        {% if forloop.last %}
            {{ item.attribute }} ]
    {% empty %}
        var js_variable{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }} = []
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

....code that gets unhappy when js_variable[n] doesn't exist.....

</script>
```

When `{% empty %}` occurs it doesn't seem to have the access to the `{{ forloop.parentloop. counter0 }}` variable, and so the variable name `js_variable[n]` is printed incorrectly as `js_variable` (without the number otherwise provided by the counter), and later code complains.

Is it the case that this variable won't be available in the `{{ empty }}` tag?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is an expected behavior. Simplifying we have:

```
{% for A ... %}
    {{ forloop.* }} is there for the 'for A ...'

    {% for B ... %}
        {{ forloop.* }} is there for the 'for B ...'
        {{ forloop.parentloop.* }} refers to the 'for A ...'
    {% empty %}
        {{ forloop.* }} is there for the 'for A ...' !!!
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

In {% empty %}, {{ forloop }} refers to the parent forloop! Change:

```
var js_variable{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }} = []
```

With:

```
var js_variable{{ forloop.counter0 }} = []
```

Comment: I didn't realise that inner forloop variable wouldn't exist in the empty case, I guess I imagined it as an empty Python sequence type, although on further reflection I can't really fit that mental model.